# c# Print a page created by xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, printing

As the title said, i'm trying to print a page, created by xaml (the page looks like to a form)

At the end of the form, I have a button with an event Click.

```
<Button Grid.Row="15" 
    Grid.Column="3"
    Click="ImpressionClick"
    Height="50" 
    Width="150" 
    Grid.RowSpan="2" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
    Content="Imprimer">
</Button>
```

My problem is: I have found how to print some text documents with C#, but i don't know how to print a page created with xaml code.

If someone know how to.

Thanks in advance.

Florian SELVA

Comment: I don't understand why the first line isn't accounted, but Hi everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`PrintDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass the interface

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
dialog.PrintVisual(this.YourLayoutName, "");
```

Comment: This is precisely what i was looking for. Thank you Sajeetharan!

Comment: So you could also just generate the layout without "displaying" it to the user? Lets say, you see a page, you press "print" and another layout is beïng printed?